# Show overlay when a method is called and then hide it when its over

Tags: angular, typescript

Ive got a method on angular which filter some values in a table.

Since there are a lot of records sometimes it can take a lot of seconds to complete so ive added an overlay with a loading icon.

Ive tried to put a boolean inside my method (lets call it `filter()` ) that is set to true when called and at the end is changed back to false.

My problem is that the value change only at the end of `filter()` so the overlay is always hidden even during the method filtering.

This is some code just to make you understand:

```
 filter(): any {
    this.filtri.push({idReport:this.idReport,status:this.status,activity:this.activity,azione:this.azione,ndg:this.ndg,dossierNumber:this.dossierNumber,dtReportFrom:this.dtReportFrom, dtReportTo:this.dtReportTo,dtActivityFrom:this.dtActivityFrom,dtActivityTo:this.dtActivityTo,nominativo:this.nominativo,causale:this.causale})
    this.filtering=true;

    if (this.activities == null) {
      this.filtering=false;
      return null;
    }

    if (this.filtri == null) {
      this.filtering=false;
      return null;
    }
    this.retValue = this.activities;

    this.retValue = _idReport
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity => activity.report.id.toString().indexOf(_idReport) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _status
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity => activity.report.status.cod.indexOf(_status) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _activity
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            activity.task && activity.task.cod.indexOf(_activity) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;

.....THEN MORE STUFF LIKE THIS....

 this.filtering=false;
    return this.retValue;
  }
```

this.filtering is the boolean used on:

```
<div class="overlay" [hidden]="filtering===false">


<div class="overlay transparent" [hidden]="filtering===false">

  <div class="hourglass"><i class="material-icons">hourglass_empty</i></div>
</div></div>
```

I hope everything is clear, thank you for the help!

***EDIT:***

Code after  Kamil Kiełczewski help:

```
filterAsync():any {
    this.filtering=true;
    setTimeout(this.filter());
 }
  filter(): any {
    this.filtri.push({idReport:this.idReport,status:this.status,activity:this.activity,azione:this.azione,ndg:this.ndg,dossierNumber:this.dossierNumber,dtReportFrom:this.dtReportFrom, dtReportTo:this.dtReportTo,dtActivityFrom:this.dtActivityFrom,dtActivityTo:this.dtActivityTo,nominativo:this.nominativo,causale:this.causale})

    if (this.activities == null) {
      // this.filtering=false;
      return null;
    }

    if (this.filtri == null) {
      // this.filtering=false;
      return null;
    }
    const _idReport = this.idReport;
    const _status = this.status;
    const _activity = this.activity;
    const _action = this.azione;
    const _ndg = this.ndg;
    const _dossierNumber = this.dossierNumber;
    const _dtReportFrom = this.dtReportFrom;
    const _dtReportTo = this.dtReportTo;
    const _dtActivityFrom = this.dtActivityFrom;
    const _dtActivityTo = this.dtActivityTo;
    const _nominativo = this.nominativo;
    const _reason = this.causale;

    this.retValue = this.activities;

    this.retValue = _idReport
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity => activity.report.id.toString().indexOf(_idReport) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _status
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity => activity.report.status.cod.indexOf(_status) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _activity
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            activity.task && activity.task.cod.indexOf(_activity) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _action
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            activity.task && activity.task.cod.toUpperCase().indexOf(_action) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _ndg
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            activity.report.customer.ndg.toString().indexOf(_ndg) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _dossierNumber
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            activity.report.dossier.dossierNumber.indexOf(_dossierNumber) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;

      this.retValue = _dtReportFrom
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            !activity.report.date ||
            this.stringToDate(activity.report.date, this.ISO_FORMAT, '-') >=
              new Date(_dtReportFrom).getTime()
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _dtReportTo
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            !activity.report.date ||
            this.stringToDate(activity.report.date, this.ISO_FORMAT, '-') <=
              new Date(_dtReportTo).getTime()
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _dtActivityFrom
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            this.stringToDate(activity.dtInsert, this.ISO_FORMAT, '-') >=
            new Date(_dtActivityFrom).getTime()
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _dtActivityTo
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
            this.stringToDate(activity.dtInsert, this.ISO_FORMAT, '-') <=
            new Date(_dtActivityTo).getTime()
        )
      : this.retValue;     
      this.retValue = _nominativo 
        ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>{
            if(activity.report.customer.hasOwnProperty("businessName")){
              return activity.report.customer.businessName.toUpperCase().indexOf(_nominativo.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }         
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.retValue = _reason
      ? this.retValue.filter(
          activity =>
          activity.report.reason.toUpperCase().indexOf(_reason) != -1
        )
      : this.retValue;
      this.filtering=false;
    return this.retValue;

  }
```

Comment: how do you call your filterAsync function? (paste code to question)

Comment: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="idReport" size="15" (input)="filterAsync()" />

Comment: do you change condition in template to `[hidden]="filtering"` ?

Comment: yes i did and the overlay now its always active. How should i initialize the variable filtering? atm its like this:   filtering:boolean = false;

Ive tried filtering:boolean and also ..boolean=true; but the overlay is always active

Comment: yes it shoud be false - but can you detect that when you NOT call filterAsync, but only change init value of `filtering` do UI changes?

Comment: mmh I dont fully understand your answer, look my updated comment above yours. Do you mean to look if the UI change when filtering is changed on init? 
If its that, no it doesnt change its always the same

Comment: this means that the problem is not with your filter function but somewhere in your .ts code and/or in your html template - put full code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` class into your component and then calling `detectChanges()` on it.

```
    constructor(
        private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
    }

   filter() {
     this.filtering=true;
     this.ref.detectChanges();

      //Do some filtering
      this.filtering=false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@Kamil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860099/kamil-kie%C5%82czewski)'s answer, this happens because the browser is not capable of rendering and running JS code at the same time. When you use setTimeout() it pushes your code to the EventLoop, and before there anything is executed your browser has time to actually re-render parts of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Run your filtering function asynchronously - e.q. remove line

```
this.filtering=true;
```

from top of your `filter()` function, and call filter function not directly but using following wrapper function (code from head)

```
filterAsync():any {
   this.filtering=true;
   setTimeout(this.filter());
}
```

However If your filter function works very long, to avoid UI freeze you can think about use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to run it concurrently/on a separate thread

UPDATE

Probably in your html template you have some bug - change `[hidden]="filtering===false"` to `[hidden]="filtering"` (the second thing is that in you use twice same condition in your template - it is correct?)

Comment: Thank you for your help but ive tried it and it doesnt work. When I try in debug and  this.filtering=true; is triggered the overlay doesnt show up because it still wait for the end of the method and its changed back to false.

Comment: it should work - update question and show your code then I can say something more

Comment: @FrancescoGiberti I also update answer because I find someting more